# Eclipseで上付き文字や下付き文字をコンパイルすると?になってしまう。

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipseで上付き文字(Superscript)や下付き文字(Subscript)をコンパイルして文字列として出したいのですが、Eclipseで以下のようなコードを実行すると`CO?`と出てしまい、2が下付き文字として出てくれないです。試しに、Web上で動く[OnlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/)で試してみるとした文字としてディスプレイに表示されました。この問題が起こる原因は何なんでしょうか？Eclipseでのコンパイルは上下付き文字を認識しないんですかね？
教えていただけると幸いです。

```java
public class Subscript
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("CO\u2082");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

お使いの環境はWindowsでしょうか。Windowsであればデフォルトの文字コードとしてMS932が選択されているはずでず。Java内部でUnicodeとして扱われている\u2082に該当の文字がないため置換文字？に変換されているのではないかと思います。試しに私もUbuntu（WSL）とWindows10で動作を比較したところ、WindowsではCO? WLSではCO₂と表示されます。加えてUbuntuでLANGをja_JP.SJISを設定した場合、Windowsの場合と同様のふるまいを見せることを確認しています。

```
hoge@DESKTOP-O85C3T1:~/workspace/smp01/target/classes$ java jp.sample.App
Hello World! CO₂
hoge@DESKTOP-O85C3T1:~/workspace/smp01/target/classes$ export LANG=ja_JP.SJIS
hoge@DESKTOP-O85C3T1:~/workspace/smp01/target/classes$ java jp.sample.App
Hello World! CO?
```

Comment: エクリプスの場合はワークスペースに対して実行時文字コードを指定することができるので、UTF-8で実行することで同様の結果が得られるはずです。
https://itsakura.com/eclipse-textcode

Comment: また、「コンパイル時に」とのことですが、「実行時に」文字の置き換えが発生するものなので、仮にコンパイル済みの.classファイルをLinuxに持ち込んだりすればその結果は期待通りのものになると思います。